# How to download the aerial linescan images from open data cube?

Tags: python, image, aerial-photography, open-data-cube

Below code gives the metadata information, using matplotlib the data can be plotted, but how can I download all the 134 aerial images in jpg format. Is there an option to download the image files directly from open data cube?

```
from datacube import Datacube
dc = Datacube(app="aerial linescan images")
linescan_datasets = dc.find_datasets(product='linescan')
print(f'\nNumber of linescan datasets: {len(linescan_datasets)}')

Number of linescan_datasets : 134
```

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a specific implementation of the data cube, which is fine, because I know what you're talking about!

If you want to download the actual source images, you can inspect the metadata documents for all the datasets you've found.

For example, do:

```
linescan_datasets[0].metadata_doc
```

You can also examine more about where the files can be found in:

```
linescan_datasets[0].uris
```

Once you have the path to the source files, you can download them all using Python or wget or whatever tool you like.